# Apple In-App Purchasing without StoreKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

While aware of the appstore guidelines, specifically IAP usage.
Our company is developing an app that would offer downloadable content [music, video, etc]
There are several challenges but one of the first is IAP on iOS.

After reading all the docs and questions [on stackoverflow], I am 100% sure we need to implement Apple's APIs to process payments and we cannot use our own.

But there exist several apps currently available on the appstore that offer products without using IAP.
one of the examples is goDaddy application where you can use the iOS app and buy a domain using a CC without IAP.

I would like suggestions if possible on how the above can be accomplished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put very briefly:

If the purchased item is to be 'consumed' on the device, such as music, extra levels for a game or whatever then iAP must be used.  If the purchased item is not consumed on the device then iAP does not have to used.  For example paying a gas bill, buying something on eBay, buying dvds or physical books from amazon; or to use your example a domain name from Go Daddy.

Comment: So, is it possible to not use StoreKit? Is Apple's IAP API open at protocol level?

Comment: That may well be a question best asked in a new post, I believe you have to use StoreKit if you have to use iAP, it was around all the way back in iOS 3 and it's still in iOS to this day!  If you are processing payments for things consumed outside iOS, as per my above answer then you can use any PSP/backend you wish to integrate with (e.g. Stripe, Paypal).